# How to calculate sum of combinations with different n and k

Tags: number-theory, modules, binomial-coefficients, contest-math, multisets

Input: $[X,Y]$ and $L$

Output : no of increasing sequence of length L and all elements should be $X\le i \le Y$  e.g: for $[6,7]$ and $2$ sequences are $6,66,67,7,77.$

For the above question my answer is the following sequence

$a+b+c+d+..$ where

$a=N$

$b=\sum_{i=1}^{N} i$

$c = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{i} j $

$d = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{i}\sum_{k=1}^{j} k$

$...$ and the no of elements in the sequence is $D = Y-X +1$

is there any formula to the above sequence?

Edit :

For the above I found that multiset is answer. Then again I encountered other issues.

how to efficiently calculate

$\sum_{k=1}^{D} {n+k-1 \choose k}$ mod 10^6+3, $1\le n,D\le 10^9$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $${n \choose m}={n-1 \choose m-1}+{n-1 \choose m}$$

Hence
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{D} {n+k-1 \choose k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{D} {n+k-1 \choose n-1} \\ 
 &= {n \choose n} + \sum_{k=1}^{D} {n+k-1 \choose n-1} - {n \choose n} \\
 &= {n \choose n} + {n+1-1 \choose n-1}+ \cdots +{n+D-1 \choose n-1} - {n \choose n} \\
 &= {n+1 \choose n} + {n+2-1 \choose n-1} +\cdots +{n+D-1 \choose n-1} - {n \choose n} \\
 &= {n+2 \choose n} + {n+3-1 \choose n-1} +\cdots +{n+D-1 \choose n-1} - {n \choose n} \\
&= \cdots\\
&= {n+D \choose n}-1
\end{align*}

Use [Lucas' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas'_theorem) to compute it for $1\le n,D\le 10^9$ (notice that $10^6+3$ is a prime number).

Comment: How come $k$ became $n-1$ in the RHS

Comment: @Sab It's because ${n \choose m}={n \choose n-m}$.

Comment: Can you point me out what are the theorems used in the derivation

Comment: and here is some finding from my side $\sum_{k=1}^{D} \binom{n+k-1}{k} = \binom{n+1}{D} - 1$

Comment: @Sab The identities used are ${n \choose m}={n \choose n-m}$ and ${n \choose m}={n-1 \choose m-1}+{n-1 \choose m}$. You may see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). From the former the answer can be written as ${n+D \choose D}-1$.